# itextsharp xmlworker remove table padding

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I'm using the iTextSharp xmlworker to generate a table grid with borders on the cells.  When it renders to the PDF the cells all appear to have cell padding or margins.  Any idea how to remove the cell padding?  I've tried using padding: 0 styles and the old cellpadding="0" table element attribute, but nothing seems to help. Attaching a pic to illustrate what it is doing. Any ideas?
[image: Example iTextSharp table]

Comment: I've tried in-line styles of margin: 0; padding: 0; on the table, tr and td elements. Including the cellpadding="0" attribute on the table element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the iText xmlworker CSS conformance list and saw a property called border-collapse.  I've never used this property. It seems to fix the problem though.

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

References: 
[Conformance List](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm)
[CSS border-collapse](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)

It isn't perfect, but close enough. Adjacent borders don't share the same pixels like HTML does, but I can shim it to exclude certain borders if needed to workaround this.